# Creating an empty scope?

Tags: javascript, architecture

Is there a way to define scope such that it's completely empty? Ideally, this would result in `window` being undefined. Or is `window` always available in every scope permutation? My initial idea was something along the lines of `apply`ing an empty object to a closure, but `window` is still defined:

```
(function() {
    console.log(this); // an empty object
    console.log(window); // the window object is still defined
}).apply({});
```

Is there any way to circumvent `window` and its associated variables, or am I just thinking funny right now?

Comment: What is the _final_ goal?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be able to control all the variables present in my scope so that, for instance, I can log everything in the current scope and have the result be only variables I've defined. I mean, obviously, that's just an example that I might be able to achieve by not logging anything with `[native code]` in its respective `toString` value, but hopefully it illustrates my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute javascript outside of the browser, you don't necesserily have a window object. For example, nodejs scripts don't have a window object, but they do have a global process object.

If you really want to have no window object available, you could clobber it with a local variable inside the new scope...

```
(function(){ var window = undefined; console.log(this); console.log(window) }).apply({});
```

This does not touch the global `window` object, which can not be clobbered, but should override it locally.

A more general wrapper, as the inner scope inherits from the outer scope...

```
(function(){ var window = undefined; (function(){
    console.log(this);
    console.log(window);
}).apply({}); })();
```

EDIT: Add general solution for all global variables...

```
// create self invoking anonymous function
;(function(){
    // enumerate all global objects (`this` refers to current scope - assumed to be global at this point)
    var globals = Object.keys(this);
    // loop through all globals
    for(i in globals){
        // don't clobber the `console` global - we will need it!
        if(globals[i] !== "console"){
            // initialise local variable in current scope with name of every global
            eval("var " + globals[i]);
        };
    };
    // create scope with empty object for `this` and all globals reset
    ;(function(){
        console.log(this);
        console.log(window);
        /* for node.js, check process, not window ... */
        // console.log(process);
    }).apply({});
})();
```

Comment: I was hoping for an answer relating to JS in the browser, and ideally I'd like to avoid having to clobber each global variable individually, because that's not as flexible as I'd like. If it's not possible, however, I'll accept this answer.